# ¿Cambio de foto de perfil de un usuario con php mysqli?

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysqli

necesito saber como hacer que un usuario por defecto contenga una foto de perfil de un usuario anónimo, y cuando cambie su foto de perfíl le aparezca la que colocó y se quite la del usuario anónimo.

Estoy usando PHP, jQuery, AJAX

Solo quiero la idéa o si pueden y necesita parte de mis codigos me avisan, xfa.

Answer (score 1):

Crea una carpeta exclusivamente para las imágenes de los usuarios + la imagen por defecto.

Cuando un usuario suba una nueva imagen, asígnale un nombre cualquiera (p.e: username_id_fotoperfil.png), copiala en la carpeta de las imágenes y almacena la ruta en una base de datos. Para ponerla colocarla simplemente utiliza php, obten la ruta con una query sencilla y listo.

Si la query no devuelve nada, pones la imagen por defecto.

Si puedes subir el código obtendrás respuestas más exactas.